# How to find files which contains preferred character in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

How can I find files and directories which contains one character for example "a"

I know that there is command  ls a*  but this find all files which starts with character

Comment: sorry, it's not clear what exactly you want. try to rephrase, adding a few examples.

Comment: I want to copy files from one directory to other but only files which contain for example  letter c

Comment: so you mean it should have exactly one character, but not starting with that character?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to find all the files whose *name* contains the letter c, or the *file* *content* has the letter c? Please rephrase your question

Comment: for example I need files which contain letter a,   there  are files with names  bertacc,   getyac,    yacv,  tyuee,  jghcl,   so I need command  which will find only those files   bertacc,  getyac,  yacv

Comment: Yes exactly I need to copy all the files whose name contains the letter for example  c

Answer (score 1):

Try the find command to copy files which begin with the "a" character.

```
find /your/source/path -name 'a*' -exec cp {} /your/target/path  \;
```

To find files which contain the "a" character use the following command.

```
grep -r 'a' /your/source/path/* | xargs cp /your/target/path
```

Comment: I think that command will find files which started with letter a

Comment: I edited the answer to show you how to copy files which match your search.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned,

```
find . -name '*a*'
```

should do what you are looking for.

However, note that this **only** looks for lowercase 'a'. If you want it to be case insensitive you can use

```
find . -iname '*a*'
```

The '*' is a **wildcard** and means that it matches any random selection of text. If for example you had instead written

```
find . -name 'a'
```

'find' will only find files with the name 'a', without any extensions.

Thus,

```
find . -name '*a'
```

will find all files ending with the letter 'a', while

```
find . -name 'a*'
```

will find all files starting with the letter 'a'.

Comment: So if I want to copy  all the files whose name contains the letter a  i need type this command   cp  '*a*' /home/user/myfiles

Answer (score 0):

`find [root_of_the_search] -name [pattern]`

for example

`find . -name "*a*"`

you can copy them like this

> cp `find . -name "*a*"` /destination/path